Excel Match Values Between Two Named Tables
I am struggling to find matches between two named tables in excel. Any help would be much appreciated please.
The scenario is:

I have two named tables in two different sheets of the same workbook. One table is named US and the other table is named India.
US table has team name, job titles, resource name, location details, their 2024 salary information, their projected 2024 bonus and their overall cost to company in 2024 - these columns are mentioned in that order.
India table is a copy of the US table. Except that, in the India table, under the column 2024, I want to extract the corresponding value from the US table based on the job title and multiply that with the internal exchange rate to get values in INR

I am trying to use Vlookup, but some error is coming and I am getting #NA. Can someone please help me understand how to go about doing this?
Thank you.
Update:
Adding tables as suggested:
US Table:
| Team                     | Resource Title          | Reporting Manager Title | Resource Name | Reporting Manager | Resource Location | Resource Type | Resource Start Date | Resource End Date | Ongoing Cost | 2024 Cost | 2025 Cost | 2026 Cost |
| ------------------------ | ----------------------- | ----------------------- | ------------- | ----------------- | ----------------- | ------------- | ------------------- | ----------------- | ------------ | --------- | --------- | --------- |
| Deployments - Technology | Business Analyst        | Sr. Business Analyst    | TBD           | TBD               | ABC               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2024       | Dec 31, 2026      | £1.00        | £0.67     | £1.00     | £0.67     |
| Deployments - Technology | Tech Delivery PM        | Tech Delivery Manager   | TBD           | TBD               | XYZ               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2086       | Dec 31, 2088      | £63.00       | £42.00    | £63.00    | £42.00    |
| Deployments - Technology | Test Analyst            | Sr. Test Lead           | TBD           | TBD               | MOP               | FTE           | Sept 01, 2087       | Dec 31, 2089      | £64.00       | £42.67    | £64.00    | £42.67    |
| Deployments - Technology | Test Analyst            | Sr. Test Lead           | TBD           | TBD               | MOP               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2088       | Dec 31, 2090      | £65.00       | £43.33    | £65.00    | £43.33    |
| Design & Experience      | Business Analyst        | Sr. Business Analyst    | TBD           | TBD               | ABC               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2025       | Dec 31, 2027      | £2.00        | £1.33     | £2.00     | £1.33     |
| PMO                      | Head of PMO             | COO                     | TBD           | TBD               | ABC               | FTE           | Sept 01, 2046       | Dec 31, 2048      | £23.00       | £15.33    | £23.00    | £15.33    |
| PMO                      | Deployment Manager - I  | Head of PMO             | TBD           | TBD               | ABC               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2054       | Dec 31, 2056      | £31.00       | £20.67    | £31.00    | £20.67    |
| PMO                      | PMO Analyst             | Sr. PMO Analyst         | TBD           | TBD               | ABC               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2055       | Dec 31, 2057      | £32.00       | £21.33    | £32.00    | £21.33    |
| PMO                      | PMO Manager             | Head of PMO             | TBD           | TBD               | ABC               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2056       | Dec 31, 2058      | £33.00       | £22.00    | £33.00    | £22.00    |
| PMO                      | PMO Manager             | Deployment Manager - II | TBD           | TBD               | ABC               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2057       | Dec 31, 2059      | £34.00       | £22.67    | £34.00    | £22.67    |
| PMO                      | PMO Sr. Manager         | Head of PMO             | TBD           | TBD               | XYZ               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2058       | Dec 31, 2060      | £35.00       | £23.33    | £35.00    | £23.33    |
| PMO                      | Deployment Manager - II | Head of PMO             | TBD           | TBD               | XYZ               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2074       | Dec 31, 2076      | £51.00       | £34.00    | £51.00    | £34.00    |
| PMO                      | Sr. PMO Analyst         | Head of PMO             | TBD           | TBD               | XYZ               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2078       | Dec 31, 2080      | £55.00       | £36.67    | £55.00    | £36.67    |
| PMO                      | Sr. Programme Manager   | Head of PMO             | TBD           | TBD               | XYZ               | RTH           | Sept 01, 2079       | Dec 31, 2081      | £56.00       | £37.33    | £56.00    | £37.33    |

For the India table, I need the exact same columns, but in the ongoing cost column, I wanted to pull data from the US table for the corresponding "Resource Title" and convert it and display in INR.
For example, in the India table, if I enter Resource Title as PMO Analyst, I want my India table to automatically update the corresponding Ongoing Cost cell to =(32*80) (assuming the internal conversion rate is 80).

Try to include some sample data, using a Markdown Table generator so it's easier for us to see what you mean.  If you have Excel 365 (as per your tag), you could probably use a FILTER function.

Or if it's a 1 on 1 copy, you could just multiply the column in your India sheet with the corresponding value in the US column.

I hope this is what you're looking for:

Only B24 is manual input;
A23 is =CHOOSEROWS(US_table,1);
A24 is FILTER(A3:A16,$B$3:$B$16=$B$24,"");
C24 is =IF(ISNUMBER(FILTER(C3:M16,$B$3:$B$16=$B$24,"")),FILTER(C3:M16,$B$3:$B$16=$B$24,"")*80,FILTER(C3:M16,$B$3:$B$16=$B$24,""));
If you just want for example I24 (ongoing cost) use FILTER(J3:J16,$B$3:$B$16=$B$24)*80.
EDIT:
Assuming your US table is named USTable:
    =IF(ISNUMBER(FILTER(USTable[[Reporting Manager Title]:[2026 Cost]],USTable[Resource Title]=$B$24,"")),
FILTER(USTable[[Reporting Manager Title]:[2026 Cost]],USTable[Resource Title]=$B$24,"")*80,
FILTER(USTable[[Reporting Manager Title]:[2026 Cost]],USTable[Resource Title]=$B$24,""))

Or for just Ongoing cost: =FILTER(USTable[Ongoing Cost],USTable[Resource Title]=$B$24,"")*80
Otherwise, change USTable to whatever tablename you're using


This is fantastic. My only concern is that the US Table is a named table. Can you please suggest how I can do this if the US Table is a named table and not a range like you have inputted? Thank you once again!

@AnantaPoolla I made an edit using Table references. Consider marking the answer if it is what you need, otherwise let me know if there needs to be more clarification or some editing.

Excellor - you are amazing. Thank you so very much!
